# File not found when using fileinput to replace pattern in file

Tags: python, file-io

I'm trying to write python code that loops through the '.fa' files in the directory, finds every line starting with ">" and replaces the entire line with part of the filename plus a number representing the substitution number.

---

**Input example:**

file: "XXX_YYY_ZZZ.fa"

'>BGC0001830.1_ORF1
MYVTAPDRIGEVQLSDGRLLGWAEWGTPDGTPVLFSPGAATSRWLGFGAEVIDRLGVRLVSVDRPGLGASTPLPGRTFADFVADLQQFTTMRELGR

'>BGC0001830.1_ORF2
MTDEESLWIRRFHPCPQAEIQLVCLPHAGGSASYFFPMSRALTPAVEVLSVQYPGRQDRRHEPCIENLSELADRVFDAIQGQTNRPLALFGHSMGA

**Expected output:**

'>XXX_YYY_contig1
MYVTAPDRIGEVQLSDGRLLGWAEWGTPDGTPVLFSPGAATSRWLGFGAEVIDRLGVRLVSVDRPGLGASTPLPGRTFADFVADLQQFTTMRELGR

'>XXX_YYY_contig2
MTDEESLWIRRFHPCPQAEIQLVCLPHAGGSASYFFPMSRALTPAVEVLSVQYPGRQDRRHEPCIENLSELADRVFDAIQGQTNRPLALFGHSMGA

---

I managed to write the code below but I'm having the follow error and I don't get why:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXX_YYY_ZZZ.fa'

```
import os
import fileinput
import sys
import re

os.getcwd()
entries = os.listdir("/../")

i=1
for filename in entries:
    with fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=False) as file:
        name = fileinput.filename()
        x=name.split('_')
        x[0:2] = ['_'.join(x[0:2])]
        final=str(x[0])
        for line in file:
            i+=1
            if line.strip().startswith(">"):
                title=">{}_contig{}\n".format(final, i)
                line = re.sub(title)
            sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Because you are listing the contents of a directory but then ignoring the full path and only using the filename when calling FileInput.

Comment: To fix that you'll need to doing something like `curdir = os.getcwd` and then in the `for` loop do a `filepath = os.path.join(curdir, filename)` to get the full path to the file.

Comment: Thank you @FiddleStix and martineau, it worked!